# Remove .entry.html from AEM Blog Post URL

Tags: url, aem

i created a blog post using OOTB journal component, using below url.
http://localhost:4502/content/community-components/en/journal.html

after creating blog post, i seen below URL for Blog Post.

http://localhost:4502/content/community-components/en/journal.entry.html/2017/07/19/sample_title-7KtT.html

Now, i want to understand how can we remove **.entry.html** from above Blog Post URL.

FYI: I'm using AEM 6.2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version AEM do you use? Please add a tag. Posting of an url with localhost are mostly useless, because some content does maybe not exists (anymore).

Comment: @reporter above Local URL comes with OOTB with AEM, so everybody have this content.

Comment: Depends on the version of AEM. I doubt that AEM5.3 and older have that.

Comment: No, am using AEM 6.2 and Added info in my question

Comment: @reporter AEM is the product name and tag for AEM 6.x so unless someone uses CQ5 tag explicitly I think it's pretty clear what minimum product version is used. A tag wiki bug should be raised if this isn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

AEM (Communities) blog posts OOTB URL format is there to help with the functioning of author and publisher environment but agreeably it is not user friendly in any form. You have the following options to fix it:

1. Use Apache rewrite rules on your dispatcher level (or the equivalent layer in other respective platform) to get rid of .journal.entry.html from the URL
2. Use sling mappings with RegEx to map to beautify the URLs

Both of these options have their uses and issues. You will need to evaluate the best approach for your infrastructure and environment. In practice, it's better to map a sub-domain (blogs.example.com) or a virtual path (example.com/blogs) and map the journal entries to it but all of this depends on the site structure.